# VB.NET NullReferenceException while trying to set 1D array in Subroutine

Tags: vb.net

`Public Property inputChordsUser As String()`

...Later in the code

```
            Dim Final As String = inputtedChord & LegitFinalExtensions
            CounterPublic += 1
            SendChords(Final, CounterPublic)
        End If

    End Sub
    Public Sub SendChords(ByRef Final As String, ByRef CounterPublic As Integer)
        inputChordsUser(CounterPublic) = Final
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` Thrown at the `SendChords` Sub. From what I can see, `inputChordsUser` is set to Nothing. Duh. I'm not trying to use it, i'm trying to set it.
Why is this? I've tried providing `inputChordsUser` as an argument with the call, but nothing.
Any good fixes?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates, the issue, not just a *...later in my code* block out of any context. Please [edit] your post to provide that MRE.

Comment: You have declare an empty array, an array with no elements. When you try to add a value to an element of the array, it fails because there are not any elements. When you don't know the size of the array in advance use `List(Of T)` where T stands for Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not dimensioned the array `inputChordsUser`.  You are not trying to 'set' the array, you are trying to set the element of the array at position `CounterPublic`.  Since there is no element at that position, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

The [documentation on VB Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) can probably answer any remaining questions.